# IIS hosted website - login works first time. Then fails. No error message

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication

We have a aspnet web application that works fine locally. No issues at all.

When published to IIS 7.5 the site loads up, lets me login in and works perfectly. I can login using my own and any other account that is registered.

Problem is - when I close the browser down and then reopen and login again it does nothing.

No error message from IIS, no 'invalid attempt' from the login controls. Nothing.

If I attempt to login with a made up username and password I get the error I expect from the login controls - 'Invalid user name and/or password'.

If I restart or simply change any settings for web site in IIS it works again once -then fails on the next attempt.

I have set 'Rapid-fail protection' to false. I have checked the logs. But I am no nearer to understanding what the problem is.

Can anybody point me in the right direction as I am losing the will to live ! :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain "it does nothing" a bit more? Is it a blank screen, does it not redirect from the login page, etc?

Comment: A few things to try.. Install remote debugging tools to the target system and attach your debugger to see what happens, or share out your local dev instance as an IIS hosted site, attach your debugger, and try to repro (with a coworker's help possibly).

Comment: I can't think of a known trap. What authentication method? It very much sounds like an issue with your code and the best way to get to the bottom is to debug it.

Comment: StingyJack - what I meant was by does nothing is - the login screen appears, I enter uname and password, press login and then the uname and password disappear and the login screen is still there. Its like it has logged me in but not redirected to the default page. If I try and call a page using the full URL I am simply redirected to the login screen again.